# Migrate Oracle database datatypes to Sql database datatypes in c# .net

Tags: c#, sql

Here we need to migrating the qracle database to sql server.
Here we are using c#.net application.

Sample code for Oracle given below.

Here we are using OracleType.Cursor, so what is the equalent in sqldbtype

```
public DataSet GetL3CompanyDesc()
{
    DataSet dsCompanyDetails = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        OracleParameter[] arrayParameter = new OracleParameter[2];
        arrayParameter[0] = new OracleParameter(IODDALConstants.GetL3CompanyDescRefCur, OracleType.Cursor);
        arrayParameter[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        arrayParameter[1] = new OracleParameter(IODDALConstants.GetL3CompanyDescCubeVersion, OracleType.Cursor);
        arrayParameter[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        OracleHelper.FillDataset(oracleConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, IODDALConstants.GetL3CompanyDesc, dsCompanyDetails, new string[] { IODDALConstants.GetL3CompanyDescTableName }, arrayParameter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bool rethrow = ExceptionLogEntry.HandleDALException(ex);
        if (rethrow)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (oracleConnection != null)
            oracleConnection.Dispose();
    }
    return dsCompanyDetails;
}
```

In the Oracle stored procedure they are passing cursors as parameters.
Is there any possibility to pass cursors as parameters in SQL.
And how to pass cursor as output parameter to the sql stored procedure from c# code?

Can anybody please help me out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a CURSOR as an SP parameter in T-SQL. Use Table-Values Parameters as illustrated in this [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).